# dns update frequency

Tags: domain-name-system

I was looking after the frequency of dns updates, since I had to change the location fo the vps that hosts the domain contents. What I ussualy read is that it takes up to 72 hours to get these changes propagated, sometimes this can be sooner based on your location.

I changed the nameservers for the domain vasco-da-gama.nl about a week ago. When I ping the domain name from different locations it still points the old vps (which does not exist anymore).

I was wondering if its normal that it can take this long for the change to point my new vps? If I might have done something wrong here, where should I look for it (it looks all ok, when I check it).
If it is reachable from your location (if so, its probably a matter of time it will propagate to my location).

Comment: http://check-host.net/check-dns?host=vasco-da-gama.nl

Answer (score 2):

DNS frequency is based on the TTL settings of a zone file which has authorized ownership of that domain.  Lowering the TTL and then incrementing the serial number with the zone file followed by a refresh will push changes to propagate however they will also update as frequently as what is specified within their own refresh intervals.

As a rule of thumb generally what I recommend is lowering the TTL at least 24 hours in advance before making changes in a host and then changing it back to original defaults later on in time.

TTL stands for time to live, i'm not sure what the best practice interval is at for ideal settings however usually a default of 24 hours is comforting area to be at.

Comment: Outside of the zone transfers that happen amongst a certain DNS zone's nameservers, there's no "push" or active propogation in DNS. The only thing one can do is wait for caches to expire and then remote resolvers will fetch a new record from the authoritative servers for the domain. But yes, you're right, lowering TTL will help speed this process along. Just wanted to be clear that you can't "push" out your DNS changes. DNS is largely a "pull" system.

Comment: Hi, although I am not completely sure anymore, I think it was set to 14400 before the change (4 hours). However I am waiting for at least 6 days for it to happen.

Comment: However, does the domain name resolve at your location?

Comment: I'm getting these results.

Non-authoritative answer:
vasco-da-gama.nl        nameserver = ns1.mijndnsserver.nl
vasco-da-gama.nl        nameserver = ns2.mijndnsserver.nl

Comment: These nameservers are correct. That should point you to: 109.74.195.149 if I am right. Does it go there at your place?

Comment: looks like ns1 80.69.83.184 & ns2 80.69.80.191 instead.
also shows an ns3 entry pointing to 85.17.201.21

Comment: I'm getting 93.158.114.54 for that domain, and the same NS entries as Nick. If it's any consolation, I know that in South Africa, one of the largest ISPs can take up to two weeks to update their DNS.

Comment: Thanks all, I contacted my dns provider and it appeared that the template was not connected to the domain in the right way. He changed this for me, and I now see that it point to the correct host.

Answer (score 1):

> What I ussualy read is that it takes up to 72 hours to get these changes

Well, what I can say is don't read crap, you'd better prefer RFCs.

DNS is all about caching. If you need small latency for your records change then use appropriate TTLs for your DNS-records (yes, they are set per record, not file, actually).